# Basic question about Taylor convergence with polynomial functions

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Let's say we have a polynomial function, say

$f(x) = x^3-x^2+x-1$

and we have to calculate both the Taylor expansion in the point $x_0=-\sqrt{\pi}$

up to a generic $n$-th degree and the Lagrange remainder.

Now, what I haven't really well understood is this: after three derivations the derivative will be constantly $0$, right? So this means the Lagrange remainder will be $0$ too and therefore the Taylor approximation from a certain term onwards won't be anymore an approximation but an exact form?

Comment: Taylor expansion best aproximate function at the point $c$ by polynomial, but if our begin function is polynomial it is easy to see the best aproximation of polynomial is polynomial (equal degree)

Comment: So the approximation is _exact_?

Comment: Yes, look this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19x213y_uk4

Comment: The approximation is exact if we go to degree 3 or higher. In degrees 0, 1 and 2, however, it is _not_ exact.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, in case of a *polynomial* the approximation to degree $\;n\ge3\;$  is **exact**:

$$f(x)=f(x_0)+\frac{f'(x_0)(x-x_0)}{1!}+\frac{f''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2}{2!}+\frac{f'''(x_0)(x-x_0)^3}{3!}=$$

$$=-\pi\sqrt\pi-\pi-\sqrt\pi-1+(3\pi+2\sqrt\pi+1)(x+\sqrt\pi)+\frac{(-6\sqrt\pi-2)(x+\sqrt\pi)^2}2++\frac{6(x+\sqrt\pi)^3}6$$